# Bulldoze bulking - optimizing workout

Tags: diet, workout-routines

I've been following the "[Bulldozer Bulking](http://muscleandbrawn.com/bulldozer-bodybuilding-bulking-system/)" workout in an attempt to gain muscle with minimum fat gain. So far it has been working well, but I'm looking to optimize the actual workout I do depending on if I'm in a "cut" cycle or a "bulk" cycle.

Currently, I'm doing a power/strength based workout during the bulk week and a more hypertrophy oriented one during the cut weeks. Is this the optimal match for such a diet?

I found [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/what-is-the-optimal-bulking-cutting-rotation-schedule) already but I'm looking for something that will more address this study in particular.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the specifics of you  routine, but there are general rules  to  consider on training  while cutting.

1) lower volume as you  are unable to  recover when calories are low.

2) High intensity to still promote muscle protein synthesis and prevent unused muscle wasting.

This looks more like power workout than hypertrophy to me.

I usually  do  full-body  workouts with compound movements and heavy weights when cutting.

Or switch to  Blade's  routine  http://borgefagerli.com/myo-reps-in-english/

Comment: Thanks Sergey, myo reps looks like it could be very useful. I haven't had any issues other than less energy in regards to #1, but #2 makes sense.

Comment: Welcome. When i cut i use extreme  approaches like  ketogenic diet or  UD2 from Lyle  McDonald so this  is important to get  into  account. I have no enough patience for soft  approaches. With less  restrictions it may be not so usefull. Lower  volume , i mean .